# Custom form container

Tags: flutter, dart, layout, containers, decoration

i need to create a container with a custom topborder in form of a cloud (like on image). It should be a background
Does anyone know, how to do it?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0WVh.png)
Thx

Comment: Kindly note that SO is not a code delivery service. So please post your latest Dart/Flutter code and describe the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [CustomClippe](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomClipper-class.html) to do what you want.

Check out this article [Custom Clipper : Wave Curve](https://medium.com/@bhoomiharkhani22/custom-clipper-wave-curve-part-1-b49853a75876) on how you can use CustomClipper to create waves.